# Wordpress last revision date

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to add a column with the date of the last revision and I use this code. Is there something wrong here?    The thing is, it doesn't work, but it doesn't give me any error message

```
add_filter('manage_pages_columns', 'add_revised_column');
add_action('manage_pages_custom_column', 'echo_revised_column', 10, 2);

function add_revised_column($columns) {

$columns['revised'] = 'Revised';

return $columns;
}


function echo_revised_column($column, $id) {

if ('revised' == $column)
    echo get_post_field('post_modified', $id);
}
```

Comment: Your question would be answered faster on: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RobertK I don't understand why this was considered off topic, as it was a code related question? I don't disagree that it was a bit vague, only those with Wordpress knowledge would've understood the context I expect... But ultimately it was a code-related question like most other questions here?

Comment: Because this question is 100% WordPress specific and there is a StackExchange site devoted to that, with lots of potential answers: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wp-admin+columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks fine to me in general.  I do something similar to add media height x width dimensions on the manage media page, and my code pattern is basically identical.

BUT: I recommend you create a constant, and use that throughout to avoid this issue, eg:

```
DEFINE('COL_NAME_REVISED','revised');
...
$columns['COL_NAME_REVISED'] = 'Revision Info';
...
if (COL_NAME_REVISED == $column)
...
```

**EDIT**: Had previously answered that key-names were mismatched, but on re-visiting the question I realised they were not mismatched.  Therefore, AFAIK the OP's code is OK.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong:

First, you probably should give your functions names with a unique prefix. For example,
user2223698_add_revised_column.  Then your function will be safe from colliding with some random plugin or theme.

Second, for your manage_pages_columns filter, you might wanna look at 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_pages_columns
to see how to add a column.  You need to provide a textual title.

Third, it's not obvious to me how you are populating this column.  Do you need to add something to the WordPress database?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Saving_Plugin_Data_to_the_Database